# Pandas reindex return NaN

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I want to reindex dataframe's rows by specific column, let's say that dataframe contain column `colX`. That's mean I need call method `df.set_index(colX)`

Consider df.head() is

```
colX colY
2.71 foo1
3.14 foo2
6.9 foo3
9.6 foo4
```

When I reindex it

```
df.set_index('colX')
df2=df.reindex(index=[9.6,6.9,3.14,2.71])
```

The output when call df2.head()

```
colX colY
9.6 NaN
6.9 NaN
3.14 NaN
2.71 NaN
```

I expect the result is

```
colX colY
9.6 foo4
6.9 foo3
3.14 foo2
2.71 foo1
```

Note: df was created by `df=pd.read_csv('foobar.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

You forget assign back after `set_index`:

```
df = df.set_index('colX')
df2=df.reindex(index=[9.6,6.9,3.14,2.71])
print (df2)
      colY
colX      
9.60  foo4
6.90  foo3
3.14  foo2
2.71  foo1
```

If use floats, there should be precision problem, possible solution is use `method='nearest'` parameter:

```
df = df.set_index('colX')
df2=df.reindex(index=[9.6,6.9,3.14,2.71], method='nearest')
print (df2)
      colY
colX      
9.60  foo4
6.90  foo3
3.14  foo2
2.71  foo1
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't downvote, Thanks that what i need.